# Haskell function type

Tags: function, haskell, types

I'm trying to understand Haskell function types right now.
Let's say I want to compose two functions f1 and f2 (suppose I don't know their definition).
The function signature of f2 . f1 is:

```
f1 . f2 :: (Fractional (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

How do I read this signature and more specifically, how do I know how to apply arguments to  this composition?

e.g. how can I read the type information of f1 . f2 to be able to write valid expressions like

```
(f1 . f2 2) 3 4
(f1 2. f2 2) 4
```

Answer (score 2):

That signature means you haven't composed them correctly. You don't get a type *error*, because in theory some madman might give functions a `Fractional` instance, but in real life that never happens. So there is no set of arguments you can apply to `(f1 . f2)` that will typecheck.

Instead, back up and look at the types of `f1` and `f2`. What are they? I predict that they are both two-argument functions, because your type is the one I get when I write

```
:t (/) . (+)
(/) . (+)
  :: (Fractional (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

You can't really compose a two-argument function, because composition is for one-argument functions. But you can partially apply the functions before composing, if you like, to make them into one-argument functions. And that's exactly what you've done in your last example, which works fine:

```
Prelude> f1 = (/)
Prelude> f2 = (+)
Prelude> (f1 2 . f2 2) 4
0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: But both `deriving via (Ap ((->) b) a) instance Num a => Num (b -> a)` and an instance for Church numerals are just sitting right there begging me to write them! :)

Comment: technically, `(/) . uncurry (+)` is also a possibility.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it's worse than that. it's actually `Fractional`. writing a `recip` method for functions should be extra fun!

Comment: @WillNess Isn't that just `recip = (recip .)`?

Comment: Thanks to all, 
may be, I should have asked for `f1 . f2 :: (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` instead.

@amalloy I understand from your answer that composing `f1 . f2` is not allowed since they are intended to have two arguments.
But: GHCI doesn't complain composing them and I thought they are "transformed" into one-argument function either way. 
I am still in the dark about the reading of the signature:
So, what is the (human) reading of   `a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` and, can I infer the application of the arguments from this reading?

Comment: What it means is "Composing these functions only makes sense if a function is itself a number". Since functions are not numbers, composing those functions makes no sense.

Comment: @amalloy: Thanks, I think I got it.